# What is a one-word (probably verb) synonym for "thinking back to" with a sort of paying homage connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, context

I'm looking for a certain synonym for "thinking back to" or "reminiscing from the past". It is used in a sentence like "This building was built with historical aspects in mind, *(?)* to the Hellenistic period". I'm not even sure if my sentence is correct, but it's sort of like paying homage to, and like taking back some element of it. I think it's a verb ending with *-ing, but I'm not completely sure. Sorry guys, it's late at night and I think I'm facing writer's block.

Here are a list of words that aren't it:

- Looking back to
- Reminiscing of
- Commemorating
- Venerating
- Lionising (??) Courtesy of Google
- Thinking back to

I should also mention that it is (probably) similar to the word 'yearning', in terms of morphology, not meaning. Or it could just be some unrelated association between the two in my brain.

Comment: You might find what you're looking for in [*SYNONYMS FOR **hark back***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hark%20back) *(**harkening back**)*. [Reconjuring?](https://www.definitions.net/definition/reconjure)

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for. I would have appreciated it if my post was answered 15 minutes earlier but thanks for the reply anyway. I sort of lost my train of thought whilst waiting for an answer...No biggie though.

Comment: Reflect (and enough prepositions to reach the minimum post length).

Comment: What about "a tribute to"? As in, "This building was built in the Hellenistic style as *a tribute to* the great buildings of classical antiquity." Reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tribute

Answer (score 0):

**Remember**

> They shall grow not old, as we that are left grow old:
>  Age shall
> not weary them, nor the years condemn.
>  At the going down of the
> sun and in the morning
>  We will **remember** them.

[R.L.Binyon](http://www.greatwar.co.uk/poems/laurence-binyon-for-the-fallen.htm)

“Remember” in this context, *referring to a person or persons*, means more than just to recall someone but also to honour them. This is explained in the Wikipedia entry for [Remembrance Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_Day)

Answer (score 0):

"This building was built with historical aspects in mind, **referencing** the Hellenistic period"

This use of *reference* as a verb connects with the definition of [reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference) (noun) as "allusion, mention", but is particularly common in writing about art, architecture, and design.

Here's an example from the art/architecture online magazine *Quondam* ([2005/05/06](https://www.quondam.com/c05/0506.htm)):

> There are many historical examples where architecture references itself, e.g., renaissance architecture referencing classical architecture, or even the second pyramid at Giza referencing the Great Pyramid at Giza.

And from the Minnesota Institute of Art ([Side chair, c. 1870, Theophil Hansen](https://collections.artsmia.org/art/124294/side-chair-theophil-hansen))

> he skillfully worked in aspects of historical styles: a classical anthemion, or decorative design of radiating petals, nestled just below the top rail, and fluted “columns” referencing Egyptian architecture that form the bottom of the chair’s feet.

Answer (score -1):

The synonym I was looking for was *hearkening back / harking back*.

Comment: hearken or harkening?

Comment: I'm confused again. What's the difference between Hearkening, Harking, and Harkening?

Comment: Generally,  today we say something harkens back to something.

Comment: So is this is sentence, 'The red motifs on this logo symbolise blood and war, hearkening back to the industry's early history.' also not correct?

Comment: hearkening is in the dictionary but I have never seen it used in an article or book.

Comment: Weird. Do they mean different things though?

Comment: According to Oxford Languages, _hark_  and _hearken_ both mean _listen_ - the first is described as 'literary' and the second 'archaic'. _Hark back_ and _hearken back_ both mean the same.

Comment: A typical sequence is [**which harks back to**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+harks+back+to%2Cwhich+hearks+back+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) For which the message *Ngrams not found: **which hearks back to*** makes it pretty obvious how we spell it. And the full Oxford English dictionary only mentions the spelling ***heark*** as having existed 1500s to 1700s. There's no mention of ***hearken*** in the relevant definitions (that's a different verb, not usually used in this construction).

Comment: ...so I'm ***downvoting*** this answer unless and until ***hearkening** back* is removed.

Comment: Please add a dictionary reference.

Comment: Comments that are not answers like this one go as comments under the question.